# Avoid adding an id-only table for a one-to-many table

Tags: postgresql, index, join

I have a table that links user IDs with external identities (one-to-many) and I would like to avoid creating a second table with just IDs.

Simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE identities (
    uid     uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    extid   text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT unique_identity UNIQUE (extid)
);
```

The logic I would like to model is that a user can log in with different external service identities, so the `uid` could possible have multiple entries; there is one-to-many relationship because each external identity can have only one real user, but real users can have multiple external identities.

However, I wonder if it would be possible to use the `uid` as a foreign key without having to duplicate this field into a second table with just one single column. Effectively, a one-to-many relationship in one table instead of the obvious JOIN between two tables.

I've thought about storing all the external IDs into an array so there would be only one `uid` entry, but the recommended GIN index doesn't seem to support unique constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE identities (
    uid     uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    extids  text[] NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX idx_unique_identity ON identities USING GIN(extids);
```

I've also considered JSONB and recursive self-joining queries, but nothing seems obvious.

So can this be done in a non-hackish way or should I give up and create a table with just one column and JOIN everywhere?

Comment: What will the distribution of array lengths be?  Any chance you can map extid to integers rather than text?  But I'd probably just make the 2nd table.

Comment: If there might be multiple entries for the same `uid` then you can't make that column the primary key. The PK should be `uid, extid`

Comment: I always recommend to model whatever the natural behavior shows. Go ahead and create the table USER with that single field, I'm sure eventually you will need more fields in that table, it always happens. then you can have the table identities but make sure you use the correct primary key as @a_horse_with_no_name commented.